# Excel Rounding VBA

Tags: vba, excel, automation, excel-2007, rounding

I have written some vba code that selects a range from a workbook and copies it to a cell in another workbook. My employer wants for this second workbook to be automated so there can be no messing around with manual entry. I need my numbers to be rounded off to the nearest thousand, so for example the number I have is -2,218,387 and I would need it to read -2,218 however at the moment it is showing as -2,218,000. this completely throws off the automated workbook and causes me so many problems. Below is the code for the copying of the ranges;

```
Public Sub InvoicedInstallments2()

Dim rng1 As range
Dim rng2 As range


Set rng1 = Workbooks("201209TB.xlsm").Worksheets("excel").range("F295")
Set rng2 = Workbooks("201210DB1.xlsm").Worksheets("UK monthly dashboard").range("AD49")
rng2.Value = rng1.Value


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your copy code is something like

```
rngSource.Copy rngDest
```

Instead of this, try

```
rngDest.Value = Round(rngSource.Value / 1000, 0)
```

Note, this will copy the *value* only, ie not the format

Comment: Chris, my copy code is the question we were talking about yesterday, you probably answer a lot of questions but the code used is yours. see edited question for code

Comment: I added the line

    rngDest.Value = Round(rngSource.Value / 1000, 0)
and amended it to
    rng2.Value = Round(rngSource.Value / 1000, 0)

It works and you are officially my hero of the week!